# Why I get wrong main bundle create date? My device is iphone 6s & ios10.2. Simulator and other iphone is correct

Tags: ios, iphone

I get main bundle create date by the below code.

```
- (NSDate *)bundleCreateDate {
    NSString *bundlePath     = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSFileManager *manager   = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:bundlePath error:nil];
    return [attributes fileCreationDate];
}
```

I get above attributes of main bundle is as follows. The create date is 1970-01-01.

{

```
NSFileCreationDate = "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
NSFileExtendedAttributes =     {
    "com.apple.installd.installType" = <01000000 00000000>;
    "com.apple.installd.uniqueInstallID" = <64366163 32353866 61366430 61333733 64373366 34623731 63306433 62333934>;
};
NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 33;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = "_installd";
NSFileModificationDate = "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
NSFileOwnerAccountID = 33;
NSFileOwnerAccountName = "_installd";
NSFilePosixPermissions = 493;
NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionNone;
NSFileReferenceCount = 24;
NSFileSize = 3842;
NSFileSystemFileNumber = 29281547;
NSFileSystemNumber = 16777218;
NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;
```

}

Comment: Hi Justin, did you find a solution for this problem? I got the same problem. But only on real iOS 10.3 devices.